# Getting old records from Facebook using the API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to fetch some historical data using the api. But when I access older and older pages, I suddenly hit one that's returning me empty data.

For example, call to this url: `https://graph.facebook.com/kenderken/posts?limit=100&until=2010-06-01T09:10:53%2B0000` returns me empty data even that there are posts on my wall that are older then 2010-06-01... (here's the last one that API returns to me: http://www.facebook.com/kenderken/posts/134367776579392 and this one http://www.facebook.com/kenderken/posts/271650467287 is from January 2010, no way to get it via API)...

Any clues on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a fairly common bug with Facebook. If you search http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/ you will find many similar reports.